# How to append data into a String list in Java

Tags: java, swing, multidimensional-array, awt

I am new to Java and Here is my code.

```
String[][] datas={{"a","b","c"},{"d","e","f"},{"g","h","i"}};

String[] onedata={"j","k","l"};
```

the thing I want to do here is that, I want to append the onedata into datas at last index value.
Please help let me know that how can I do this.

Comment: You are not using `List`s but arrays. You cannot simply add a new value to an array (apart from replacing an existing one) because their length won't adjust.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! As other users stated, the array length is immutable. You have to setup a new array, and set the new values at specific array positions. You can find many examples in google, please try to make some research before to ask question as it will help to get better answers and positive feedback in your question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an ArrayList because their sizes are mutable. For example:

```
String[][] datas={{"a","b","c"},{"d","e","f"},{"g","h","i"}};
List<String[]> datasList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(datas));
String[] onedata = {"j","k","l"};
datasList.add(onedata);
datas = datasList.toArray(new String[datasList.size()][]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The things you are dealing with are arrays (`String[]`) and multidimensional arrays (`String[][]`) in Java, not lists. Their length is fixed. Therefore to append a new item to an array in such way that the length increases (so not by replacing the last item in the current array) you would need to create a new array with length *n+1*, assign the old values to the first *n* indices and then the new value to the index *n+1*.